# How do I save event handlers using XAMLWriter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-3.0

I am using xaml writer to write the all objects in a window. While all objects are successfully saved, button click events are missing. Is there a way I could save the events as well, do I need any custom implementation ?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you want. Could you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you should write something like this:

```
<x:Code>
    <![CDATA[
    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         //your logic
    }
    ]]>
</x:Code>
<Button Click="Button_Click">Clac</Button>
```

Your xaml file should specify x:Class attribute in the top tag. also you should see [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750494%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and use [this site](http://www.google.com/) to find answer faster :) GL&HF.